# R-Excel VBA: how to extract values returned by GetArrayToVBA?

Tags: r, excel, vba

I'm trying to write an R-Excel vba addin and am having trouble using `GetArrayToVBA`.

Example:

```
RInterface.StartRServer
RInterface.RRun "mytst<-4"
Dim tstVar As Variant, tst As Double
tstVar = RInterface.GetArrayToVBA("mytst")
tst = CDbl(testVar)
MsgBox "count = " & CStr(tst)
RInterface.StopRServer
```

Results in messagebox showing `count = 0`. I was expecting `count = 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a VBA issue. You can't typecast a 1x1 array into a double with CDbl() to get the value that's in that array. You have to give it the index (0,0) that you want from the array. The following works:

```
RInterface.StartRServer
RInterface.RRun "mytst<-as.matrix(4)"
Dim tstVar As Variant, tst As Double
tstVar = RInterface.GetArrayToVBA("mytst")
tst = CDbl(tstVar(0, 0))
MsgBox "count = " & CStr(tst)
RInterface.StopRServer
```